# How to use credential from JSON file to use Google drive API in a cloud function

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, credentials

I've a cloud function in Python that need to access a Google Shared Drive.
I've get a JSON file with the credential of the account (can't be a service account because the shared drive required user from the domain) with this doc: https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#desktop-app
[how I get the JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXrTz.png)

The JSON file looks like:

`{"installed":{"client_id":"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"xxx-my-project","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"xxx-my-client-secret","redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]}}`

In my cloud function, I use this lines:

```
import google.auth
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
[...]
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('client_secrets.json', scopes=None)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

I've put the client_secrets.json file at the same level as my main.py.

At first I've needed to remove: {"installed": and the last } because the error was that client_id etc... parameters were missing.

The error I got now and don't understand why is:

> google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_request: Missing required parameter: refresh_token', {'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'Missing required parameter: refresh_token'})

Where could I get this value  and why is the downloaded JSON file not working without modification ?

I've tried adding:
"refresh_token":"" or "refresh_token":None but it was not OK ;-)

Thanks for you help in this.

Comment: I've read here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1 that refresh token are optional but that doc becomes a bit too complexe for me ;-)

Comment: And here: https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/1.19.1/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html it's says it can be specified (so I suppose it can be not specified):
refresh_token (str) – The OAuth 2.0 refresh token. If specified, credentials can be refreshed.
And:
property refresh_token
The OAuth 2.0 refresh token.

Type
Optional [ str ]

Comment: Don't use service account key file in a cloud functions (and elsewhere also!!). Review your design, runtime service account on Cloud Functions is enough for that!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for your answer.
I can't use a service account because it will have a email adresse that is not on my domain (something like xxx@xxx-iam.gserviceaccount.com) and the shared drive I need to access is limited to user on my domain only.

Comment: Try that ack: Create a Google groups (which will have your domain name) and add the service account email to the group and try. If your org is not well configured, it could work!

Comment: I know it will not be accepted by cybersecurity team because I don't manage the Google  group so if someone is added to that group, he will have the same access on the shared drive.
Do you think, it's not possible to use an oauth2 account as credential in a cloud function ?

Answer (score 0):

as the others have mentioned, if you're inside the google cloud environment there are other ways to call the API that don't require you to do so with a creds file

That being said, I got my API script to work copying the three blocks of code in this guide: https://blog.zephyrok.com/google-drive-api-with-service-account-in-python/